# Can I use google Firestore on the device which doesn't have google service?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I really need the realtime data sync function for local DB and Google Firestore perfectly meet my requirement. But my only concern is: Does Firestore support mobile and table devices which don't have google service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Cloud Firestore SDK on a device without Play services, but you will not be able to use it in tandem with Firebase Authentication, which currently does require Play.  As a result, you can not effectively use any security rules that depend on a UID or anything else related to Auth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer！ Another following question is why iOS platform can use Firestore without google service?

Comment: If you have another question, please post that separately.